# Specified function return value, yet error is appearing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am for some reason getting this error from my code, yet I have specified the return type.

`Unexpected non-void return value in void function`

```
func performSearch(region: MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKLocalSearch.Response {
    print("Searching...")
    let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "Coffee"
    searchRequest.region = region
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
    search.start { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error").")
            return
        }
        return response
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the completion block that is passed to *search.start* shouldn't have a return value. Since the return statement is inside the completion block, it is treated as a return statement for the completion block, and not for *performSearch*.

Comment: Is there a way to return it while still inside the search block? As otherwise the function will return a value before the search has finished

Comment: In newer versions of Swift you can use Async / Await, read here: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/async-await/